# Probability: number of songs chosen

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, independence

There are 14 singers at The Voice 2021 getting ready for a public show and each needs to choose an unordered playlist of 3 different songs from 50 total songs. Each singer chooses a playlist of 3 songs; any subset of 3 songs out of 50 is equally likely. The singers choose songs independently of each other,i.e.,it is possible to reuse the same song across different singers, but a singer cannot use a song more than once.
The music director needs to buy the rights to the songs the singers choose for any show. How many songs should director expect to buy the rights to for the show?

My approach for this problem is that I am going to call X as  random variable representing the number of songs the director need to buy. However, I am having some problem calculating the PMF. I wonder if this is the right approach and if so how to calculate the PMF ?

Comment: Calculate the probability for a song to be chosen at least once, then use linearity of expectation.

Comment: Why not start by calculating (1) the chance a singer chooses a particular song; and then try (2) the chance a song is chosen once, twice, three times, etc.  Do you think that all 50 songs could be chosen?  If so, how would the songs be distributed amongst the singers?